# Программа суммирования чисел выдает ошибку

Tags: java, исключения

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    int n = 0;
    int S = 0;
    String current = "";

    System.out.println("Введите количество чисел для суммирования");
    n = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Введите числа для суммирования");
    current = sc.nextLine();

    ArrayList<String> row = new  ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(current.split(" ")));

    ArrayList <Integer> introw = new ArrayList <Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
        introw.add(Integer.parseInt(row.get(i)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < introw.size(); i++) {
        S = S + introw.get(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Сумма S = " + S);
}
}
```

Скриншот ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибки тоже текстом лучше выкладывать

Answer (score 1):

`nextInt()` - считывает значение до перевода каретки `\n`, таким образом `nextLine` считывает именно его (этот самый перевод каретки).

В итоге либо надо писать `nextLine()` даже на первой строке и уже потом конвертировать через `parseInt()`, либо добавить еще один `nextLine()` после `nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

Метод `nextInt()` просто читает первое числовое значение из входного потока, но не "переводит" сканер на следующую строку - после этого вызов `nextLine()` читает всё, что осталось в текущей строке (а там уже ничего не осталось).

Самое простое решение - добавить ещё один вызов `sc.nextLine();` сразу после чтения первого числа и прочитать потом уже следующую строку.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите числа для суммирования: ");
        String current = sc.nextLine();

        boolean prevIsDigit=false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char ch : current.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                sb.append(ch);
                prevIsDigit=true;
            }
            else if (prevIsDigit) {
                sb.append("@");
                prevIsDigit=false;
            }
        }

        int result = 0;
        for (String s : sb.toString().split("@")) result+=Integer.valueOf(s);

        System.out.println("Сумма S = " + result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Напишите так. Вам не надо количество цифр, их можно вычислить в зависимости от пользовательского ввода. Просто вводите строку с цифрами , используя любые разделители, и все будет подсчитываться. Так проще и надежнее

Comment: Только отрицательные числа вы, кажется, не учитываете.

Comment: ну так это уже на "самостоятельное изучение" на ряду с рефакторингом и добавлением дробных чисел. все на блюдечке - тоже нехорошо. я просто показал один из возможных путей решения